# Monotonic function $f$ - Riemann Stieltjes Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f \in R(\alpha)$ ( where $\alpha$ is some function ) on $[a,b]$ and if for every monotonic function $f : $

## $\int_a ^b f~ d \alpha = 0 $

then, prove that $\alpha$ must be constant on $[0,1]$

**Proof:** By integration by parts :

$\int_a ^b f~ d \alpha + \int_a ^b \alpha~ df = f(b) \alpha (b) -f(a) \alpha (a) $ . Substituting $\int_a ^b f~ d \alpha = 0 $ in the above equation, we get :

$\int_a ^b \alpha~ df = f(b) \alpha (b) -f(a) \alpha (a) $

How do I move ahead?

**EDIT :** An example in the text :

Given any point $c \in (a, b)$, we may choose a monotonic function $f$ defined as follows :

$f(x) =   \begin{cases} 
      0 & x \leq c \\
      1 &  x > c 
   \end{cases}
$

> So, we have $\int_a ^b \alpha ~df= \alpha(c) = \alpha(b)$

Hence, it was concluded that $\alpha$ is constant. I have a little trouble understanding the result in the blue box. Please tell me how this result came.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are constant functions considered monotonic in your text/course?

Comment: yeah, they are ..

Comment: Then $f \equiv 1$ may take you a step forward. Shall $\alpha$ be monotonic too?

Comment: No, $\alpha$ is not given to be monotonic in the problem ..

Comment: @DanielFischer May I please ask why we have chosen $f \equiv 1$, don't we need to prove it for all monotonic functions?

Comment: It's given that $\int_a^b f\,d\alpha = 0$ for all monotonic $f$. A nonzero constant $f$ then gives you $\alpha(a) = \alpha(b)$. If $\alpha$ were supposed to be monotonic, that would be it. But without that assumption, we must do some more work. Step functions would help.

Comment: As an alternative suggestion, showing the contrapositive might be easier, too: if $\alpha$ is not constant, then there exists a monotonic $f$ so that $\int f\,d\alpha\neq0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Please see my edit in the blue box. Do you think the result in the blue box is true?

Comment: @Clayton. Uhm, Suppose, $∫fdα≠0,$ but, since, nothing is known about $\alpha$ what can we say about this integral

Comment: @VHP: choose your $f$ carefully and you can show $\int f\,d\alpha$ is nonzero. Don't start with assuming the integral is nonzero, just that $\alpha$ is not constant.